# Provider for SQL Server is not Register On Local Machine

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, connection-string

I used the following code to connect C# with database

```
string connStr =   "Provider=.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server"+
" Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdf;Integrated  Security=True";

try
{
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
    {
        conn.Open();

        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(selected_querry, conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                using (OleDbDataAdapter dAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(selected_querry, conn))
                {
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    try
                    {
                        dAdapter.Fill(ds);
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error: Failed to Fill the required data Field from the DataBase.");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Not Open");
    }

}
catch (Exception e)
{       
    MessageBox.Show("Error: Failed to retrieve the required data from the DataBase."+e);
    return;
}
```

When i run the code i always get the following error

```
Provider for SQL Server is not Register On Local Machine
```

Comment: Why are you using OleDb library for connection. I suggest you should use System.Data.SqlClient

Comment: What sort of application is this Windows, Web? What platform are you working? 32 bit 64 bit? is this error occuring at devlopement time or on deployed version?

Comment: @dotnetstep i use this method it also give same error

Comment: @Amit it is windows stand alone application and i am working on 64 bit platform

Comment: I also suggest you to use OleDbConnectionStringBuilder to build your connection string. In this case provider name will be added behind the scenes

Comment: I suggest you check this website: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/

Comment: @SmartDev i check the site but it can not solve the problem :(

Comment: @  Andrey we have to add PRovider in OleDbConnectionStringBuilder() and if i add it error will be still remain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an OleDb connection, you need to specify an OLE DB provider rather than a .NET provider in the connection string and specify the OLE DB connection string keywords Server (instead of Data Source) and Trusted_Connection=yes (instead of Integrated Security=SSPI):

```
string connStr =   "Provider=SQLNCLI11.1"+
    ";Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdf;Trusted_Connection=Yes";
```

SQL Server OLE DB providers include:

- SQLOLEDB: legacy MDAC/WDAC provider
- SQLNCLI: SQL Server 2005 Native client
- SQLNCLI10: SQL Server 2008 Native client
- SQLNCLI11: SQL Server 2012 Native client

However, in .NET applciations, it is best to use a managed provider.  For SQL Server, the .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server (a.k.a SqlClient) will perform better, especially with large result sets.  Use SqlConnection, SqlCommand, etc. and omit the provider from the connection string since it is implicit.  Your connection string should work if you remove the Provider specification.

Comment: Guzman - SQL Server   nice and thanks for you answer i solve my problem using SqlConnection i want to ask one simple question is it good to use SQL server for window desktop application which just store little amount of data or i should use ms-access for it ??

Comment: Either solution will likely meet your needs.  The considerations include 1) LocalDB is free whereas Access requires a user product license 2) SQL Server is strictly a back-end database but Access can also provide a UI (not relevant with a custom C# app) and 3) SQL Server is a more powerful database engine with additional features.